# Reference request for texts on polar coordinates.

Tags: reference-request, polar-coordinates

I am looking for books, papers, and other texts on polar coordinates. I want such a text to rigorously define polar coordinates, and also derive the polar coordinate equations for common geometric shapes, such as lines, circles, ellipses and parabolas. I am almost sure that there are such texts out there.

Comment: Pretty much any analytic geometry textbook should do this.